# Radius of convergence of complex series

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, binomial-coefficients

I need help for this exercise:

We consider the following sequence of function $(f_n)_{n\ge0}$:

$$f_n:\mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$$
$$z \mapsto \frac{1}{p_n}[z(1-z)]^{4^n}$$

where $p_n$ is the biggest absolute value of a coefficient that appears in the expansion of $[z(1-z)]^{4^n}$.

We expand each $f_n$ so that $\sum_{n \ge 0}f_n$ writes as a power series around it's origin, that is as $\sum_{n \ge 0}a_k z^k$. Compute the radius of convergence of this series.

Well I started with this:
$$[z(1-z)]^{4^n}=[z-z^2]^{4^n}=\sum_{k=0}^{4^n}\binom{4^n}{k}(z)^{4^n}(-z)^k$$
But how do I find now the biggest absolute value and carry on?

I know that the radius of convergence is calculated like this:
$$r = \frac{1}{\lim\limits_{b \rightarrow \infty} sup(\sqrt[n]{|an|})}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because we are dividing by $p_n,$ we have

$$f_n(z) = \sum_{k=0}^{4^n}c_{k,n}z^{4^n + k},$$

where each $|c_{k,n}|\le 1.$ For each $n,$ we have at least one $|c_{k,n}|= 1.$ Note further that the powers of $z$ occuring in the expansion of $f_n(z)$ are $z^{4^n}, z^{4^n+1},\dots, z^{4^n+4^n}= z^{2(4^n)}.$ Thus from one $n$ to the next, the expansions of $(z(1-z))^{4^n}$ do not comingle. Conclusion: The power series of $\sum f_n$ has the form

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nz^n,$$

where $|a_n| \le 1$ for all $n,$ and $|a_n|=1$ for infinitely many $n.$ It folows that $\limsup |a_n|^{1/n}=1,$ and hence that the radius of convergence is $1.$

Answer (score 0):

The largest value of
$\binom{2m}{k}$
is at
$k = m$,
the central binomial coefficient.

You can then use
Stirling's approximation
($n!
\approx \sqrt{2\pi n} (n/e)^n
$)
to get what you want.